Connection failed between my ESP8266 to the API
This is my code for ESP8266 trying to send a request to the API to get a response.
But when I am trying to scan a QR code the output is always connection failed, at first I thought it was because of the internet connection but it turns out that the internet connection is fine.
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* password = "********";

String apiEndpoint = "https://host/api/read_qr_kds";

String raw_data = "";
bool new_data_available = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char input = Serial.read();
    
    if (isPrintable(input) || input == '\n') {
      raw_data += input;
    }

    if (input == '\n' && raw_data.length() > 1) {
      Serial.println(raw_data);
      sendQRDataToAPI(raw_data);
      
      raw_data = "";
      new_data_available = true;
    }
  }

  if (new_data_available) {
    // Process any response or take action as needed
    new_data_available = false;
  }
}

void sendQRDataToAPI(String data) {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    HTTPClient https;
    
    String link = apiEndpoint + "?raw_data=" + data;
    Serial.println("Sending HTTP GET request to: " + link);

    https.begin(client, link); // Use client for HTTPS
    https.setTimeout(10000);
    
    int httpCode = https.GET();

    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      Serial.println("HTTP GET request successful.");
      String response = https.getString();
      Serial.println("API Response: " + response);

      // Parse the JSON response
      StaticJsonDocument<512> doc;
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, response);
      
      if (!error) {
        int orderId = doc["qrData"]["OrderID"];
        Serial.print("OrderID: ");
        Serial.println(orderId);
        const char* status = doc["status"];
        Serial.print("Status: ");
        Serial.println(status);
      } else {
        Serial.print("JSON deserialization failed: ");
        Serial.println(error.c_str());
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println(https.errorToString(httpCode));
    }
    
    https.end();
  } else {
    Serial.println("WiFi not connected. Cannot send data.");
  }
}


well look what you get on the server. At first reading, the scanned QR code should be url encoded as soon as you send it with a GET request (personally I would choose POST with octet-stream)

@mrmcwolf I also try using POST but I am getting same output. the data I get from the QR code is correct and the link is correct. I can access the link using my browser. I don't know what else is wrong

what exactly you are getting as an error is not clear. Http response with status other than 2XX or some socket error?

I am getting -1 http code

I'm not familiar with this http client, but judging by the error - you have a lower level (sockets) problem. If everything is fine on wifi, try unencrypted traffic (http instead of https) to eliminate certificate issues. also try with an IP address instead of a domain name to eliminate DNS traffic issues.

the problem most likely starts from calling https.begin(client, link); whose answer you do not check.

@mrmcwolf I tried to print https.begin(client, link); and the output is 1 to the serial monitor, indicating that the initialization of the HTTPS client was successful
